# how to parse JSONArray with 2 type of JSONObject?

Tags: java, arrays, json

I'm trying to parse this JSONArray that has 2 different types of JSONs.
`{"key":"a","value":"b"}` and `{"key":"c"}`.
i don't know the order of these JSONs in JSONArray; it could be something like this:`[{"key":"a","value":"b"},{"key":"c"},{"key":"d","value":"e"}]`.

how can i parse this JSONArray?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually do something like this

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(
                "[{\"key\":\"a\",\"value\":\"b\"},{\"key\":\"c\"},{\"key\":\"d\",\"value\":\"e\"}]");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) arr.get(i);
            Iterator<String> keys = obj.keys();
            while (keys.hasNext()) {
                String key = keys.next();
                //your logic for checking if object has both keys or one key goes here
                if (key.equals("key")) {

                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: how should i find out that what my json type is? @Akash

Comment: or you can check the size of keys, if its length is 1 then its of type-1 if length is 2 then its of type-2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON.simple to convert string data to JSON array. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple/1.1.1

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

    String data = "[{\"key\":\"a\",\"value\":\"b\"},{\"key\":\"c\"},{\"key\":\"d\",\"value\":\"e\"}]";

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) parser.parse(data);

    for (Object obj : jsonArray) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

        //Verify json type by checking for value

        if (jsonObject.get("value") == null) {
            // Type 1 key
            System.out.println(jsonObject.toJSONString());
        } else {
            // Type 2 key and value
            System.out.println(jsonObject.toJSONString());
        }
    }
}
```